# Email tag synchronization through Microsoft Exchange server

Tags: email, thunderbird, exchange

My email provider operates a Microsoft Exchange server through which I send and receive email, using Thunderbird (on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). I do this both on a desktop computer and on a separate laptop.

Everything works alright, except for the synchronization of message tags. If I tag an email in Thunderbird on the desktop using the '1' key, then this tag does not show up on the laptop and vice versa. Fortunately, this kind of tag synchronization *does* work on other email accounts that I have.

So:

> Is there a way to get tag synchronization to work through a Microsoft Exchange server? (Assuming that using another email provider is not an option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that [Davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) works well for me.

(Davmail provides a POP/IMAP/SMTP/Caldav/Carddav/LDAP Exchange and Office 365 Gateway.) I've been using it for quite a number of years, most recently with Amazon [Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) as the Java runtime. There are times when the Exchange IMAP interface just doesn't work properly - and this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to the problem by setting up a script that synchronizes the file

```
~/.thunderbird/[profile-name]/ImapMail/[mailserver]/INBOX.msf
```

between the two Thunderbird instances. This file is apparently where the information about message tags is stored locally. And so far, simply copying the file from one Thunderbird instance to the other is working well.